# Github actions commit and push to same branch

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have a github actions workflow setup that triggers on any pull request to prd branch.

So let's say I created another branch called "test" and set up a pull req on prd branch. My github actions workflow will run a python script to create some files in branch test.
Now I want to commit these new files and push it back to test.

Or in short : How do I make changes to files within a branch using github actions and then push those changes back to the same repo.

An example use case could be :-
A developer pushes a branch and creates a pull req. My github actions workflow is supposed to check for certain mandatory files within that repo and if that is not found, create them and add that to that developer's repo.

This is what I tried :-

```
git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
git add -A
git commit -m "Added files"
git push
```

This is not pushing changes back to my test branch and I do not know how to do it. Please help.

Comment: git pull/fetch after your push

Comment: No, it does not work.

Comment: You run five Git commands, but no commands that actually create or update any files. The `git add -A` step will have nothing to do, and the `git commit` step will say that there's nothing new to commit, so `git push` will have no new commit(s) to push either. If that's not your complete set of commands, well, imagine if you drove a car into a service shop and asked them to fix the problem with the car you *didn't* drive into the service shop...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to push.

I would also recommend using the [Configure git credentials action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/configure-git-credentials) rather than setting the config yourself.

```
- uses: oleksiyrudenko/gha-git-credentials@v2-latest
  with:
    token: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
- run: |
    git add -A
    git commit -m "Added files"
```

Comment: Without pushing it does not show the newly added files in test repo.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the complete action, please?